# Should all values returned by `**_reply` method be freed in XCB?

Tags: xcb

I was reading the docs and in some exmaples, even though they don't mention it, they free the return value of a `**_reply` method. Should all values returned by `**_reply` method be freed in XCB?

Comment: Yes. With regular old `free`.

Comment: Thanks very much @CoffeeandCode if you can move that to answer I would love to accept